# What's the difference between margin:auto and justify-content / align-items center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

To center both horizontally and vertically simultaneously, there are two simple options:

First

```
.outer {
  display:flex;
}
.inner {
  margin:auto;
}
```

Second

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

What's the difference? In what situations would we use one over the other?

Comment: both solution does the same . what is missing here is an height to .outer such as height:100vh;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your first example...

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.inner {
  margin: auto;
}
```

... the `auto` margin applies only to the flex item and centers that one flex item within the container.

In your second example...

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You are centering items from the container level. This code will center *all* items.

Also, keep in mind, if you use both methods at the same time, `margin: auto` [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534254/flex-auto-margin-not-working-in-ie10-11) prevail.

> [**8.1. Aligning with auto
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension
>
> If free space is distributed to auto margins, the alignment properties
>   will have no effect in that dimension because the margins will have
>   stolen all the free space left over after flexing.

***But the most important difference***, for practical purposes, may be the behavior when a flex item exceeds the size of the container. When this happens, you lose access to parts of the item when using the container-level code. The item disappears from the screen and is not accessible via scroll.

To overcome this problem, use `margin: auto` for centering to work properly.

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276)
- [Center a flex item vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) (see Box #56)

IE Bugs:

- [Flex auto margin not working in IE10/11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534254/flex-auto-margin-not-working-in-ie10-11)
- [Flexbox auto margins don't work with justify-content: center in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34862068/3597276)